# Перевод строки в двоичный код

Tags: java

Необходимо преобразовать строку состоящую из символов (Пример String a = "abc") в массив битов (Пример вывода : 01001101 01010100 01101011) Как это лучше реализовать ?

Comment: гляньте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/917190/5330439)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s = "abc";
for (byte b : s.getBytes()) {
    System.out.println(
        String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0')
    );
}
```

Берём последовательность байт из строки и переводим в двоичное представление, используя метод `Integer.toBinaryString()`, дополняя нулями слева до 8 символов, если необходимо.

При необходимости можно указать конкретную кодировку для перевода символов в байты, например, `s.getBytes("cp1251")`.